# How to get document.popupNode in Firefox Electrolysis windows

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, e10s

I am trying to write an add-on for Firefox Electrolysis. When I open an e10s window and right click on a page element, document.popupNode is not available for e10s window.

```
var WindowListener = {
    setupBrowserUI: function(window) {
        //
    },
    tearDownBrowserUI: function(window) {
    },
    // nsIWindowMediatorListener functions
    onOpenWindow: function(xulWindow) {
        var domWindow = xulWindow.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                                 .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindow);
        // Wait for it to finish loading
        domWindow.addEventListener("load", function listener() {
            domWindow.removeEventListener("load", listener, false);
            // If this is a browser window then setup its UI      
            if (domWindow.document.documentElement.getAttribute("windowtype")=="navigator:browser") {

                domWindow.document.getElementById('contentAreaContextMenu').addEventListener("popupshowing", function(event){

                    let document=event.currentTarget.ownerDocument;
                    let prompts = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/embedcomp/prompt-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPromptService);
                    prompts.alert(null, "Test", document.popupNode);                    

                }, false);

            }

        }, false);
    },
    onCloseWindow: function(xulWindow) {
    },
    onWindowTitleChange: function(xulWindow, newTitle) {
    }
};

let wm = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"].
       getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator);
// Wait for any new browser windows to open
wm.addListener(WindowListener);
```

You can use test code in Scratchpad. After running test code, open a new normal Firefox window and right click inside a web page. Prompt alert appears for the document.popupNode.

But if a new e10s Firefox window is opened and right clicked, it does not show anything.

How can I get the document.popupNode in e10s windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `document.popupNode` because the XUL document didn't pop anything up at a node. Instead it received a message from the child process that told it to display the menu at certain screen coordinates.

Instead, use `gContextMenu.target`, which is populated from `gContextMenuContentData.event.target`.

`gContextMenu.target` is available all browser windows, while `gContextMenuContentData.event.target` is only available in e10s windows.

Of course, `gContextMenu` is only valid when a popup is about to show or showing.